# ColladaLoader: Could not find the skeleton for the skin

Tags: three.js

I was trying to render a primitive character I made in 3dsmax, but seems like there's something wrong with my exported DAE file or just ColladaLoader is unable to process it correctly.

Scene consists of an animated biped skeleton, simple rigged character using Physique modifier, one static box and an animated one.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var size_width = window.innerWidth;
  var size_height = window.innerHeight;
  var player;
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, size_width/size_height, 0.1, 1000);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(size_width, size_height);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera.position.x = 100;
  camera.position.y = -50;
  camera.position.z = 7;

  camera.rotation.x = 1.4;

  var player_loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

  player_loader.load( "running_babe.dae", function(collada) {
    player = collada.scene;
    init();
  });

  function init() {
    scene.add(player);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
</script>
```

But all I get are those two boxes and a error:

```
ColladaLoader: Could not find the skeleton for the skin.
```

Here's exported DAE file I use - http://touhou.ru/upload/ff72eb0b40adf5c97286a1bcb164e1f0.DAE

Any suggestions?

---

Update: After rigging character with skin modifier I came up with the same result - could not find the skeleton for the skin.

Here's the link to exported dae with skin modifier - http://touhou.ru/upload/af6ba52b7bff5fa2b0f6ba3f704a3b77.dae

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and spent days playing with exporter settings before i started reading the threejs colladaloader source and figured it out. so in case you haven't solved it yet, here's what you have to do:

First: when you export your model from max, make sure none of the elements in your scene have the same name as your filename (or your geometry wont show up this has something to do with generated ids in the DAE file)

Now, 3DSMax somehow neglects to export a  node, so you have to add that manually:

1. open the running_babe.dae file in a text editor
2. look for an <instance_controller url="...."/> node and rewrite it to:

> ```
> <instance_controller url="....">
>     <skeleton>#xxxxx</skeleton>
> </instance_controller>
> ```

wherein 'xxxxx' is the id(=element/bone name in 3dsmax) that is the root element of your skeleton hierarchy. and don't forget the 'hash' at the beginning! :)

hope that solves it for you. i haven't tried animation yet, but i will now, and let you know if there's anything missing from this solution.

> edit: nevermind, apparently i just scratched the surface of the tip
>   of a huge frigging iceberg.. seems like getting collada(from 3dsmax
>   2013) + skinned animation working is a pain.. i'll look at writing a new json exporter. 
>   the format seems straight forward and well documented, plus, there's the old .ms file 
>   from github to start from. good luck to you! if you find something, be so kind as to post 
>   your method here, would you? :)

Comment: haha, thank you for your answer, but animation is the most important point for me here. I've spent too much time trying to get it working, but finally gave up and got to learn some blender basics lol

Comment: aremes, your iceberg was never really there. See my answer.

Comment: @AndyRay I dont have enough reputation to comment on your answer :) But thanks for that tip! I haven't been doing anything webgl-related in a while, but i'll be sure to remember that when i get around to it!

Answer (score 2):

The default plugin that comes with 3ds max does not work. You need to use the [OpenCollada](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA/wiki/OpenCOLLADA-Tools) plugin. Then you can follow the [collada loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html) example. You get bones, animations and all!